# Connecting to Azure SQL Server database using R within a docker container

Tags: r, sql-server, azure, docker

I'm trying to connect to a Azure SQL Server via R running in a Docker container that is instantiated by a timer trigger in Azure Functions. Locally in R on my machine I can connect to my SQL Server without issue. It seems though, that when I test the docker image locally the resulting swagger endpoint I'm expecting for the timer trigger refuses to open in the browser. This is also the case if I try using docker compose to resolve timer trigger storage requirements.

I've previously set up a custom timer trigger using this method connecting and uploading to a Blob container. This is working successfully triggering at the interval I've specified with the image/container hosted on ACR. See here for brief overview of the process that I undertook: https://blog.rmhogervorst.nl/blog/2021/01/22/running-an-r-script-on-a-schedule-azure-functions-serverless/

See also here for the docker compose overview: https://blog.rmhogervorst.nl/blog/2021/01/18/testing-azure-functions-locally-with-azurite/

What I would like help with is understanding as to:

1. Why is my swagger API endpoint not working in this time around?
2. Is this to do with my trying to access SQL Server within a docker container? In my R script I am using the odbc package, and pass all the relevant information (driver name, database name, uid, password etc).
3. Do I have to expose ports within the container? If so, which ones and why.

My end plan is to host the container on ACR in the same method I set up for the blob variant.

My experience previously had been that we testing locally it would throw an error initially due to the timer trigger needing allocated storage, but once it retried I was able to access the swagger docs at the address, trigger the function to run my R code by posting to the endpoint. However in this instance I can't access the docs at all.

My docker file is below:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:4-appservice 
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com \
    --recv-key '95C0FAF38DB3CCAD0C080A7BDC78B2DDEABC47B7'
RUN echo "deb http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian bullseye-cran40/" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
     libxml2-dev \
     libsodium-dev \
     libsodium23 \ 
     -t bullseye-cran40 r-base
     
# See about installing ODBC drivers here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017
# Note that the driver version installed needs to match the version used in the code
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18 unixodbc-dev mssql-tools
# R packages for odbc must be installed after

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
 libcurl4-openssl-dev \
 libssl-dev libxt6 && \
 mkdir -p ~/.local/share/renv && \
 R -e "install.packages('renv', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"

### splitted the copying into parts so the rebuiliding times are quicker
COPY renv.lock /home/site/wwwroot/renv.lock
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
RUN R -e "renv::restore(prompt=FALSE)"
COPY image_timer_predict_trigger/ /home/site/wwwroot/image_timer_predict_trigger
COPY host.json /home/site/wwwroot/host.json
COPY handler.R /home/site/wwwroot/handler.R
COPY handle_this.R /home/site/wwwroot/handle_this.R
COPY run_job.R /home/site/wwwroot/run_job.R
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution, but I have some advice.  I have installed ODBC drivers into a Linux-based container and connected to databases with DBI and odbc.  It took some care to specify the connection string correctly.  I like to store the connection strings in a `odbc.ini` file that's in the repository and then copied into the container with a Dockerfile `COPY` statement.  With this .ini file installed, you can do some testing of the connection with the command line utility `sqlcmd` outside of R simply from the shell.

I can also recommend debugging things from inside the container with `docker exec`.  This will allow you to test things from the terminal or the R console.  `odbc::odbcListDrivers()` is a useful thing to run.

Here is a line in a Dockerfile to copy the .ini file.

```
COPY mssql_odbc.ini /etc/odbc.ini
```

Here is what the contents of the .ini file will look like.  For MS SQL (I don't know about Azure databases), there's a peculiar syntax of the `Server` string where the address and port must be separated by a comma.

```
[mssql]
Description = ms sql odbc
Driver = /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql18/lib64/libmsodbcsql-18.3.so.2.1
Database = db
Server = server,port
Encrypt = no
TrustServerCertificate = no
ServerForceEncryption = no
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion on this Arthur. As you say I think part of problem was getting a correct connection to the database. I've managed to get that part to work locally, but once it's in a Azure custom handler it doesn't work. I know there's lots of documentation about using Azure functions and SQL but tbh they go over my head a little. As this was a 'play' project I've decided to opt for the easiest solution - upload my data as csv to blob storage. Not ideal, but as it's going to be relatively small I think it's simplest approach.